# How sync Shopify template code in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify

I run my Shopify in local. I created a new template for a single product in the dashboard in below address:
https://yalda-dev.myshopify.com/admin/themes/125958160523?key=templates%2Fproduct.test.json

but I can't see it in VScode.

[picture1: shopify code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNTrT.png)

[picture2: vs code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5rBG.png)

Answer (score 0):

To syncrhonize files between remote shopify and your development environment one way is to use the Shopify Cli - https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/cli
And check this guide https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/cli/getting-started#use-an-existing-theme

After you install it you run

`theme get --env=yalda`

And that will update all your files or

`theme get --env=yalda path/to/file`

to only update one file.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuu, It's worked for me :)

 command: shopify theme pull